# Why gloox standard example src/examples/ft_send.cpp does not work in my machine?

Tags: c++, file-transfer, gloox

I'm using code example from [here](http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/17503290)

And running it in Debian as

```
g++ -o tr ft_send.cpp -lgloox -pthread
./tr example@gmail.com/resource  ./file
```

Then it sends me request to accept file and I press `accept`. But then it prints

```
log: level: 0, area: 131072, <iq type='error' to='sender@gmail.com/glooxsendf1E777155' id='uid:502f38b2:2ae8944a' from='mmariya123@gmail.com/QIP9CA3B3AF'><error code='404' type='cancel'><item-not-found xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>
ft request error
log: level: 0, area: 262144, </stream:stream>
ft_send: disconnected: 17
ce: 18
```

and disconnects from server.
What can be problem? Can anybody help me?
May be thing is in

```
      f->addStreamHost( j->jid(), "192.168.100.20", 6666 );
      // you should obtain this using disco, really:
//       f->addStreamHost( JID( "reflector.amessage.eu" ), "reflector.amessage.eu", 6565 );
//       f->addStreamHost( JID( "proxy.jabber.org" ), "208.245.212.98", 7777 );
```

But I do not know how to correct it.

Comment: The error code "404" obviously indicates that something is "not found". Could be the paths to the files, or that you don't have the proper permissions to see the files (even if they are there).

Comment: @Bo Persson I'm trying this `addStreamHost( JID("proxy."+client->server()), client->server(), 7777 );` and now it says                      `log: level: 0, area: 131072, <iq to='mmaaria123@gmail.com/glooxsendf04C7FDC8' id='uid:502f52dc:625558ec' type='error' from='sender@gmail.com/glooxsendfile'><query sid='uid:502f52dc:19495cff' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams'><activate>mmariya123@gmail.com/QIP09A0DF00</activate></query><error code='503' type='cancel'><service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know gloox. Just tried to interpret the error message.